# how know windows7 os bit version, 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, operating-system

Can anyone tell me how to find which version my os runs, either 32 or 64bit.. In mycomputer rightclick menu i dont find properties.

I dont find any earlier posts related to this

[image]

Comment: Start -> Control Panel -> System. Or Right click on Computer in Windows Explorer and select Properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the command prompt, using:

`wmic os get osarchitecture`

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel>System and you should see your O.S. version and if its 64bit
Look at the image below,"System type".
[image: The Windows 7 System Panel]

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in cmd to open system properties.

```
sysdm.cpl
```

To find out if your computer is running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows in Windows 7 or Windows Vista, do the following:

```
    1. Open System by clicking the Start button, right-clicking Computer, and then clicking Properties.
    2. Under System, you can view the system type.
```

If your computer is running Windows XP, do the following:

```
Click Start.

Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.        

 - If you don't see "x64 Edition" listed, then you're running the 32-bit version of Windows XP.
 - If "x64 Edition" is listed under System, you're running the 64-bit version of Windows XP.
```